# MySQLで、インデックス名の大文字小文字に言及している、参考になりそうなコーディング規約みたいなものはありますか？

Tags: mysql

MySQLでインデックス名を確認したら、「すべて大文字のインデックス名」と「すべて小文字のインデックス名」が混在していたので、いずれかに統一したいのですが、参考になりそうな(業界で標準とされているような)コーディング規約か命名規則みたいなものはありますか？

[CREATE INDEX ステートメント](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/create-index.html)へアクセスしましたが、インデックスキー名に使用可能な文字は分かりませんでした

Comment: とても古いこんな記事 [Is named index case sensitive in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13300476/9014308) があり、そこからたどった最新版 [11.2.3 Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) と少し前の版？の機械翻訳 [9.2.3 識別子の大文字と小文字の区別](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) には仕様としてのインデックス名には大文字小文字の区別が無いように見えます。他にこんな記事では全て小文字にしていそうです。[Is there a naming convention for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7899200/9014308), [How I Write SQL, Part 1: Naming Conventions](https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[別質問での回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/98884)にも書きましたが、「業界標準」なんてものはありません。適当に検索して、自分で決めてください。検索もできないというなら、私の方で検索しておきましたので、明記されているサイトだけをピックアップしました。下記から選んでください。

小文字

- [データベースオブジェクトの命名規約 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/genzouw/items/35022fa96c120e67c637)
  `idx_<テーブル名>-NN`だけあるが、テーブル名は小文字で、NNは二桁数字の連番
- [オブジェクト命名規則](https://github.com/it2911/tidb_database_develop_manual/blob/main/2.%20%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E5%91%BD%E5%90%8D%E8%A6%8F%E5%89%87.md)

大文字

- [ネーミングルールとネーム辞書](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/naming_rule.html)
  テーブル名とカラム名からだが、それらはおそらく大文字みたい

他、多くのサイトでは明記はされていませんでしたが、インデックス名にテーブル名やカラム名を含む場合が多いため、テーブル名やカラム名の大文字小文字にあわせていることが多いように見受けられました。