# データベースのカラムの順番について、コーディングルールみたいなものはありますか？ もし内規を作るとしたら？

Tags: データベース設計

質問
データベースのカラムの順番について、コーディングルールみたいなものはありますか？
ない場合に、もし内規を作るとしたらどんな感じになりますか？

質問背景
プロジェクト毎に毎回異なるDB設計を行うと思うのですが、なるべく共通化できるところは共通化しておいたほうが後々管理もしやくすなると思いました。

属人性を排するため、カラムの順番について言語化するとしたら
・「idカラムが最初」で「更新日時カラムが最後」ぐらいですか？
・一般的にはこうしている、みたいなものがもしあれば知りたいです。

Comment: Google 検索すると [ほぼ同じ内容の質問と回答が teratail で見つかります。](https://teratail.com/questions/97539) 、こちらは参考になりませんか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98665)とあわせて回答します。

---

コーディング規約やデータベースの命名規則等について、どうしても「業界標準」というものが欲しいようですが、そんなものは存在しません。一部の言語やDBでは、開発元が提供している場合がありますが、そういった場合は少ない方ですし、それに従う必要もありません。

では、みんなどうしているのかというと、**今の開発状況に最も適していると思われる規則** を採用します。それはどんな物かというと

- ずっと前から組織で使ってきた規則
- どこかの組織や誰かが作った規則
- 採用する言語やDBやフレームワーク等で開発者が標準として提供している、または、デファクトスタンダードだと言われている規則
- 上の規則からいいとこ取りをした規則
- そこから自分のこれまでの経験からカスタマイズした規則

と言った感じです。柔軟な組織であれば、組織の規約を状況に応じて変更したりする事もあれば、他の人が慣れているからと変えたくないと言う理由で頑なに同じ規約を使い続けるという事もあります。それらは単純に、どれが良い、どれが悪い、ではなく、今ある状況でにおいて、妥協も含めて、なるべくベターなものを選択しているに過ぎません。あなたが求めるような、完璧で究極の規則なんてものは存在しません。色々なものを参考にしながら、悩みながら、自分で決めるしか有りません。組織に属しているのであれば、その柵の関係で、時代遅れのような規則でも従う必要がある場合もあります。

---

自分では決められないので、どうしても **標準** が欲しいというのなら、私が **標準** を提供しましょう。「Ruby on Railsでの生成規則に従う」です。主なルールは次のようなものです。

- テーブル名もカラム名もインデックス名も全て小文字。
- テーブル名はモデル名の複数形(例: Userに対して`users`)。
- 最初のカラムはプライマリキー`id`で、64bit整数値(DBが対応していればUUIDも可)。
- モデルの属性のカラムは、モデルの情報を表示や編集するときに並ぶ属性の順番(後述も参照)。
- 最後のカラムは作成日時`created_at`と更新日時`updated_at`で、日時型。
- 外部キーは`【モデル名の単数形】_id`(例: Userに対しては`user_id`)。
- インデックス名は`index_【テーブル名】_on_【カラム名】`。複合インデックスの場合はカラム名を`_and_`で繋げる。プライマリーやユニークであっても付け方は同じ。
- 単純な多対多用テーブルは、名前は辞書順で`【テーブル名】_【テーブル名】`で、カラムはそれぞれの外部キーのみ、プライマリキーは無し。

Ruby on Railsにはscaffoldというものがあり、一度にモデル、ビュー、コントローラーを作ることができます。`rails g scaffold book title:string author:references price:intger`のような感じでBookモデルとそれに関するビューなどを作ると、表示の順番もカラムの順番もtitle、author、priceになります。その前後に`id`と`created_at`/`updated_at`が付くという形です。カラムを表示するときのUIとカラムの順番が同じと言ってもいいでしょう。

これらの規則は、MVCに詳しい人達が色々な経験と議論の末に、様々なDBに対して、MVCのフレームワークでモデル名などから自動生成する際にベストだと思われるものを採用した結果です。質問者さんは色々と悩んでどうしても自分では決められないようなので、ひとまず、Ruby on Railsと同じ規則に従ってみてはいかがでしょうか？この規則が全ての状況でベターになると言うわけではありませんが、より良いモノが欲しいという話をするには、より具体的な話、どんな物をどれを使ってどんな体制でどのようにしてどれぐらいの期間で作るかというのが無いと、誰も決められないと思います。

Comment: 回答内容をたたき台にして、今の開発状況に最も適していると思われる規則の方針を決めていきたいと思います。大変参考になりました